# How to compile mixed kotlin and java from command line?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, compiler-errors

I hava two files:

A.java

```
class A{

}
```

B.kt

```
class B:A(){

}
```

I try to compile B.kt like this:

```
kotlinc -cp A.java B.kt
```

But compile error:

```
WARN: zip END header not found: A.java
B.kt:3:10: error: unresolved reference: A
```

How show I compile B.kt ?

Comment: Compile `A.java` with `javac` then pass the result of that (`A.class`) to `kotlinc` on the classpath.

Comment: You have this tagged Android.  If you're building android, you'd just do gradlew :module:assembleDebug or assembleRelease.  Gradle will build both for you.  If this isn't an Android project, remove it from the tag list.

Comment: @BoristheSpider  But if A.java use Other.kt , I want to know a general solution

Comment: @GabeSechan yes, but i want to know how gradle do it.

Comment: General solution is to run `kotlinc` over both Java and Kotlin _sources_. Then run `javac` over the Java sources with the output of `kotlinc` on the classpath. The correct solution, however, is to let a build tool do it for you…

Comment: @BoristheSpider but `kotlinc -cp A.java B.kt`  not work.

Comment: That’s because it’s not what I said at all. You don’t add the Java _sources_ to the classpath - that makes no sense.

Comment: @BoristheSpider but the error is `unresolved reference:A` . Can you give me a demo? I try kotlinc-jvm, it's the same error , thanks~

Comment: Sorry, but it’s very simple. Your Java **source file** cannot be on the **classpath** as it’s not a class. It needs to be added to the **sources** for compliation. How did you add your Kotlin **source file** for compilation? I’m going to leave reading man pages as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I understand and it works , thank you~